# mongodb connect callback not firing when mongodb is offline

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm working on a small nodejs-express project and wanted to use mongodb with it. Here's my code that establishes connection to my local instance of mongodb:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var client = mongodb.MongoClient;
var mongourl = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
client.connect(mongourl, function(_error, _database) {
    assert.equal(null, _error);
    if (_error) {
        _response.writeHead(500, respHeaders);
        _response.end('{"error":"Cannot connect to mongodb instance"}');
        console.log('Cannot connect to mongodb instance');
    } else {
        console.log('Connected to mongodb instance');
    }
    _database.close();
});
```

when mongodb is up and running, I get the callback fired with error as null. However, when mongodb is turned off, the callback never fires. I'm on MacBookPro, Yosemite, node version 4.4.1, express 4.14.0 and mongodb 2.2.4

Am I doing anything wrong ?

Comment: Sounds ok. Who is going to turn mongo on?

Comment: Me :-) I'd start it on a different terminal. Complete code here: https://github.com/weijuly/rest-api-sim/tree/develop

Comment: What is your node MongoDB driver version? Newer version might have better error reporting.